# Error on SQL Inner Join Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, inner-join, oledbcommand

I have two saved queries in Microsoft Access called `Current_Ratio` and `Quarterly_Growth_Rates`.  These two saved queries share the same `Primary Key`.  But they may not all contain the same data.  How do I use and `Inner Join` statement to show the data from these saved queries side by side?

Here is the code:

```
con.Open()
Dim cmd3 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker) AND ((IIF(C.Period = 4, C.Year + 1, C.Year)) = G.Year) AND ((IIF(C.Period = 4, 1, C.Period + 1)) = G.Qtr)", con)
Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd3.ExecuteReader()
Dim da As New DataTable
da.Load(reader)
DataGridViewCalculations.DataSource = da
reader.Close()
con.Close()
```

I get an error at `da.Load(reader)` saying:

> The provider could not determine the Double value. For example, the row was just created, the default for the Double column was not available, and the consumer had not yet set a new Double value.

**Additional Information:**

I've been successfully running this code for a while now using an abbreviated set of data of approximately 15 stocks. I just scaled up the amount of data to approximately 6,000 stocks and now I am having this problem.

The problem is with the Current_Ratio query. If I run `SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio` I get the error. But not if I run `SELECT * FROM Quarterly_Growth_Rates`

Comment: What is column type for year in current_ratio table

Comment: what is column type ticker?

Comment: can you try this "SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker) Where ((IIF(C.Period = 4, C.Year + 1, C.Year)) = G.Year) AND ((IIF(C.Period = 4, 1, C.Period + 1)) = G.Qtr)"

Comment: @AshReva Ticker column type is Text

Comment: Does it work if you remove IIF condition. Just do "SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio AS C INNER JOIN Quarterly_Growth_Rates AS G ON (C.Ticker = G.Ticker) "

Comment: @AshReva I tried both of your suggestions and got the same error message each time.

Comment: so you get error even when you remove IIF condition? If yes then its something in your column Ticker which you have used to join

Comment: @AshReva Would it matter if both saved queries don't contain all of the same Tickers?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46531/discussion-between-ashreva-and-gromit1)

Comment: I've been successfully running this code for a while now using an abbreviated set of data of approximately 15 stocks. I just scaled up the amount of data to approximately 6,000 stocks and now I am having this problem.

Comment: The problem is with the Current_Ratio query.  If I run `SELECT * FROM Current_Ratio` I get the error.  But not if I run `SELECT * FROM Quarterly_Growth_Rates`

Comment: did you removed special characters from current_ratio table?

Comment: It turns out that there are not special characters in the current_ratio table. Only the Quarterly_Growth_Rates table

Comment: I have other similar saved queries called `Total_Debt_to_Assets_Ratio`, `Operating_Margin`, and `Free_Cash_Flow`.  `Total_Debt_to_Assets_Ratio` and `Free_Cash_Flow` return the values without error.  But `Operating_Margin` returns the same error as the `Current_Ratio`

Comment: i am running out of ideas and questions too :(  This is really strange. Are there too many number of columns in table which are giving you error? What are column types in those?

Comment: Same number of columns with same names and column types.

Comment: I'm thinking that there may be a problem with the calculation that creates the saved queries.

Comment: What calculation and what is saved query?